What’s the exact difference between an error, fault & failure?
When a rocket explodes or something goes wrong, the anomaly is called something. I think a well known example is with SpaceX Starship rockets flights, where they set certain goals for their launch and called the rest "icing on top of the cake“. Therefore when they achieved the goals, SpaceX called them a success. While in the media the first few flights were considered failures, since there were explosions visible.
Of course there are differences between errors, faults & failures. If I write a code and it doesn’t work, then I say the code has an error, not a failure. In rocketry, it is probably important to differentiate the exact difference between them. Even @DavidHammen said in a comment that it is important to distinguish the difference. What are the criteria needed to declare an anomaly as an error, fault or failure?

That's going to depend on the standards of whoever's doing the declaration, I should think.

@Cadence You are correct. However, those who use one terminology while others use a very different terminology can still talk with one another.

Abort, retry, ignore?

As Cadence mentioned in a comment, the meaning varies from group to group. I'll use what I'm familiar with. Others interchange the meanings. However, the distinctions remain.
Suppose the valves to a thruster designed to be restartable get stuck in the off position on the last time it was commanded to be off. Some will call that a failure, others will call it a fault. However, until that thruster is commanded to be on the fault/failure will not manifest itself as a problem. That might take just seconds, but it might also take hours (or longer) during which the problem might go undetected. (It will be much quicker if the valves have a built-in error detection capability, but many do not.)
Aside: It will probably be much longer if good old Murphy (Murphy's Law) has his way. This enables the possibility of an apparently simultaneous double fault, something that many reject as highly unlikely. The first failure was lurking; it just happened to manifest itself when a totally independent second fault occurred.
In the case of a lack of such built-in equipment, until that failed-off thruster is commanded on, there will be no indication of such a problem. The problem manifests itself as an error: the thruster did not turn on as commanded. The problem might eventually become observable. (It might take some time as some vehicles are what I called Mack trucks on ice with a tiny Volkswagen engine and no brakes.)
It has been difficult for me to distinguish between faults and failures in the above because thruster valves that are stuck off are inevitably called "failed off", even by groups that would otherwise distinguish that as a fault. I have yet to discuss what a "failure" is. That to me is a very special term. It means the problem is not recoverable.
In the case of human space flight, a failure means one of two things: The failure means that one or more crew members died or were severely injured, in which case the vehicle must return home as soon as possible. That is a flight failure. No one dies or is injured in a less severe failure, but the mission cannot proceed to success. That is a mission failure.
Similar concepts exist for uncrewed vehicles. Failure to meet the short-term promises made by the space agencies to the politicians who voted to fund it are one thing. The failures that eventually cause long-term space missions to end are another thing. Failing to meet even short-term objectives results in Congressional hearings, companies losing their contracts, and people losing their jobs. The Voyager spacecraft will eventually succumb to power loss failure. Those vehicles were by all accounts a massive success. There are times when failure is not an option but there are other times where failure is inevitable.
Well before a vehicle is flown, potential problems with the vehicle are analyzed bottom to top (failure modes and effects analysis (FMEA), pronounced as "fee-mah") and top to bottom (fault tree analysis (FTA)). FTA starts with enumerating all of the bad things (the bad effects of a failure) that might happen to a vehicle and chase these down to root causes. FMEA starts with enumerating all of the bad causes of things that might go wrong (root failures) and proceeds upward to determine what the effects of those failures might be. Think of a directed acyclic graph (DAG). FMEA and FTA are in a sense inverted versions of the same DAG.
Both FMEA and FTA can identify areas where "failure is not an option". Those areas will have very specialized FDIR capabilities built into the spacecraft. I spelled out the acronym first (the acronym is pretty much universal) because each letter has multiple expansions:

F stands for failure or fault. As I noted above, different groups use those terms differently.
D stands for detection or diagnosis. In some cases, built-in test equipment detects the problem shortly after it occurs. In other cases, more sophisticated diagnostic techniques must be used.
I stands for isolation or identification. Identification goes hand in hand with detection and diagnosis. Isolation on the other hand entails a first cut at walling the problem off.
R stands for reconfiguration or recovery. In the case of my hypothetical failed-off thruster, the vehicle switches to a redundant thruster (or a redundant set of thrusters) by reconfiguring the vehicle. Recovery involves doing something to fix the root problem, possibly to a reduced capacity.

I'm sure I have not covered the possibilities of what the letters F, D, I, and R mean to different groups. Except for the very pedantically correct, the acronym is always FDIR (pronounced "fidder").
I worked on FMEA and FDIR on many vehicles. I'll give two specific examples that I worked on. One was the X-38, which almost flew. (A bean counter who later became the head of NASA canceled X-38 for the sole reason that its budget pretty much matched the overruns by the ISS program.) X-38 was indeed a Mack truck on ice with very slippery wheels, a very lousy VW engine, and of course, no brakes. It used a very unique set of thruster alignments, designed so that much fewer than the nominal set of a huge number of thrusters were needed. The problems were twofold: (1) the thrusters were weak, so it took time for the signal from a failed-off thruster to rise from the noise, and even worse (2) thruster fail-on was also a possibility due to the use of commercial off-the-shelf equipment to translate commands to the computer to voltage outputs to the thrusters. While thruster fail-off is a PITA, it is manageable because every sane vehicle has some amount of thruster redundancy. Thruster fail-on is a much nastier problem. In the case of X-38, my software was the only non-avionics software that was allowed to shut down a computer gone wild. To make matters even more interesting, some of the behaviors from a failed on thruster looked very much like the behaviors of a different thruster failing off. As that vehicle never flew, so I don't know whether it truly did work. I worked on thruster FDIR on multiple vehicles. I never did know if the FDIR worked because those vehicles' thrusters happened not to have failed.
A totally separate example was the system used to remove carbon dioxide from the breathing atmosphere (the Regenerative CO2 Removal System, RCRS for short) on long duration Shuttle flights. NASA used a Rube Goldberg device to accomplish this. Half of the device removed CO2 from the cabin atmosphere, stored in a bed. The other half of the device vented accumulated CO2 in another bed to vacuum. Eventually the two halves switched roles via a very complicated sequence of plumbing changes. There was a possibility of a direct connection between cabin atmosphere and vacuum if things went very haywire. The RCRS did have built-in test equipment to detect possible problems. The built-in recovery was very simple: Close all valves, clear all electronics, and shut the system down. (It would be up to the astronauts to switch to the backup capability.) The problem was that clearing the electronics meant that it would take hours to diagnose the problem unless someone had been watching over the system at the time of failure. They had six seconds before all evidence of the problem was erased. I was asked to build something that could do better than this. This software "flew" in Mission Control rather than onboard. It worked properly (no false positives, no false negatives) for several flights -- until one flight in which alarms went off everywhere. It was the RCRS! The six seconds had already passed, but my FDI software detected the problem before those six seconds transpired and identified what the problem was. My software did not provide any sort of reconfiguration or recovery. This was a joint solution by intelligent people in Mission Control and astronauts that provided that missing R part. They used a knife and gray tape (aka duct tape) to come up with a solution. Between an RCRS reconfigured to be half efficient (using a knife and duct tape!) and the backup lithium hydroxide canisters, the space flight was able to go on to complete its planned mission. It's nice (for the sake of the mission) when ones FDIR software doesn't have to work. It is however nice when ones FDIR software does indeed work.
Note very well: This has been a rather short answer to what oftentimes is multiple semester long (or longer) graduate level courses.

you mentioned Murphy, so I'm obliged to mention that he was a real person, Major Edward A Murphy, because way too many people don't know that (though I wouldn't be surprised if you did)

"errors" can also be human in nature: Swapping cables when building the craft, sending the wrong command, flipping the wrong switch.

@ErinAnne Most people also get the original meaning of Murphy's Law wrong. (Murphy's Law has itself been murphied by Murphy's Law.) The original sense had a tech who was given very explicit instructions on how to wire a circuit. The tech of course did that bass ackwards. The original form, as cited by Major Murphy stated that if there are two ways to wire a circuit,  a tech will inevitably do it the wrong way. Now it of course means anything that can go wrong will, at the worst possible moment.

@ErinAnne I myself was murphied by the original form of Murphy's Law. I had started working at 6:00 AM and was called into work around noon (I worked from home long before COVID). When I awoke from the dead and came in at 9:00 AM, nothing worked. (It certainly did work at 3:00 AM! I wouldn't have left if it didn't.) iIt turned out that the circuit was wired bass ackward. Our solution was simple: Unpeel the hand-made on-off switch, rotate by 180°, and stick it back on. Simple!

@DavidHammen I have been variously delighted and horrified over the years by solutions to Murphy's original law (make the connector asymmetric with obvious cues on how to wire it/how it should be wired, like strict color coding) and workarounds to those solutions (it doesn't fit in that orientation so hammer it in til it does, which I think caused a Proton rocket failure?)

@ErinAnne, and also Organic Marble: I think it's almost instinctive with techs to make a mess of things. Doesn't fit? Hammer it in. Diagram doesn't make sense? Do it the wrong way (and don't call the designers; they need their sleep). That "Don't remove before flight" flag: Leave it on (and leave the cover on as well). Ack!

@OrganicMarble A whole lot of human induced errors occur prior to flight. The preflight checkout should have uncovered those errors, but in many cases it does not.

@DavidHammen one of the worst in-flight messes of any shuttle mission I supported was caused by a mid-level bureaucrat not routing a document for approval months prior to the mission.
